# How to call an async Command from inside another async Command in Xamarin.Forms in MVVM?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just as the title says, I'm trying to do this:

[image]

but I get this error.

Do you guys know what should I do ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => {    
         Map.Pins.Clear();
         Map.MapElements.Clear();
         await ExecuteLoadPinsCommand();    
  });
```

Comment: it worked but it created another problem, the method ExecuteUpdatePinsCommand still says "this async method lacks "await" operator", what should I do ?

Comment: you can make this method ExecuteUpdatePinsCommand return type as Void like this: private void ExecuteUpdatePinsCommand() {}

Comment: But will it not make the execution of the code not wait for ExecuteUpdatePinsCommand to finish executing if I make it void ?

Comment: Your ExecuteLoadPinsCommand() method is awaited already it will wait